# How to profile PyCuda code with the Visual Profiler?

Tags: python, profiling, cuda, pycuda

When I create a new session and tell the Visual Profiler to launch my python/pycuda scripts I get  following error message: `Execution run #1 of program '' failed, exit code: 255`

These are my preferences:

- Launch: `python "/pathtopycudafile/mysuperkernel.py"`
- Working Directory: `"/pathtopycudafile/mysuperkernel.py"`
- Arguments: `[empty]`

I use CUDA 4.0 under Ubuntu 10.10. 64Bit. Profiling compiled examples works.

p.s. I am aware of SO question [How to profile PyCuda code in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317691/how-to-profile-pycuda-code-in-linux), but seems to be an unrelated problem.

**Minimal example**

pycudaexample.py:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
        drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),
        block=(400,1,1), grid=(1,1))

pycuda.autoinit.context.detach()
```

**Example settings**
[image: Screenshot of used settings]

**Error message**

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: It isn't unrelated at all, the answer is exactly what needs to be done. The CUDA context needs to be explicitly destroyed at the end of execution so that the buffers holding the profile data are flushed and written to disk. I profile python code in executable files with hash bangs all the time, and it just works, as long `pycuda.autoinit.context.detach()` is called before exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to profile PyCuda code in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317691/how-to-profile-pycuda-code-in-linux)

Comment: @talonmies, I added pycuda.autoinit.context.detach() to the end of my script, but still the same error message.'Execution run #1 of program '' failed, exit code: 255'

Comment: Post a minimal repro case in your question and someone might have time to take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong with the way you are specifying the executable to the compute profiler. If I put a hash bang line at the top of your posted code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and then give the python file executable permissions, the compute profiler runs the code without complaint and I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that you can use.

**Launch the Script Interpreter**

```
Launch    python
Arguments "/pathtopycudafile/mysuperkernel.py"
```

**Launch a Executable Script**

```
Launch    "/pathtopycudafile/mysuperkernel.py"
Arguments [blank]

mysuperkernel.py must be executable (chmod +x)
mysuperkenrel.py must have a #! to specify the path to the interpreter
```

See @talonmies answer