# How to profile (visually) a CUDA code which is implemented in a python package through C extension?

Tags: python, cuda, profiling, cprofile, nvvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to profile PyCuda code with the Visual Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857384/how-to-profile-pycuda-code-with-the-visual-profiler)

The CUDA visual profiler (nvvp) requires an executable entry for profiling, but my CUDA code is implemented in a python package by through C extension. Is there anyway to do the CUDA profiling in this python package? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot specify to NVVP the application that is loading the python C extension as the application to profiler?

Comment: @Greg Smith Thanks for your reply, but NVVP can only be initiated with an executable, and my application entrance is a python script and has to be invoked by python. May I missed something here...

Comment: How about launching with python.exe?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate post. Please close it.