# Profiling PyCUDA code with nvvp in CUDA 6.5

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, profiling, pycuda

Judging by past StackOverflow questions (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317691/how-to-profile-pycuda-code-in-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857384/how-to-profile-pycuda-code-with-the-visual-profiler)), it seems that one should be able to profile PyCUDA programs using nvvp. When I tried running nvvp in CUDA 6.5 on a PyCUDA script that runs without any problems from the command line, profiling failed with the following error:

```
Unable to profile application.
org.eclipse.core.rntime.CoreException: Reference to undefined variable args
```

Has anyone successfully used nvvp 6.5 with PyCUDA? I'm using PyCUDA 2014.1 manually built against CUDA 6.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. The script itself has executable permissions and `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top, and I specified the script path as the file to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, nvvp can get confused by certain bash functions in one's environment (see this [post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/643950/environment-problem-for-nvvp/) for another example). I found the function by searching through the output of `env` and unset it using `unset -f`.